# is there any lock for eclipse project source code

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-kepler

i am developing one project in eclipse Kepler version 
i want to put a lock for eclipse project source code, so that in other machines my project source code should not work in other eclipse.

for this any solution is there ? guide me on this.
    is there any tool for this type of security issues?.

thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not clear what you are asking. But if someone has the source code for a project you will not be able to stop them from using it.

Comment: Why do you want to lock this source code? Please explain your use case.